# Separate and get single variable from dictionary collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = ctrl_args.ToList();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in list)
            {
                if (pair.Key == "zoomCordinates")
                {
                    ZoomCoordinates = pair.Value;
                }
             }
```

and pair.Value contains the below output.

Output:

```
pair.Value
Count = 2
    [0]: {[zoomPosition, 0.24274899847278192]}
    [1]: {[zoomFactor, 0.4409862474463452]}
```

I want to separate "**zoomPosition**" and "**zoomFactor**" value from **pair.Value** and store in a variable alone. 
**Ex.**

```
var zoomPos=0.24274899847278192;
var zoomFact=0.4409862474463452;
```

Anyone could please help me.

Thanks,
Bharathi

Comment: I don't see where is the problem... Looks like you have a custom class for that, just use your ZoomCoordinates.zoomPosition and zoomFactor and store them somewhere else...

Comment: what is the *actual type* of object stored in `pair.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

That is how you could store values in the variables

In this example I have added keyvaluepair values in the list. As you specified you get those value from `ctrl_args.ToList()`

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("zoomPosition", 0.24274899847278192));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("zoomFactor", 0.4409862474463452));

var zoomPos = default(object);
var zoomFact = default(object);

foreach (var pair in list)
{
     if (pair.Key.ToLower() == "zoomposition")
          zoomPos = pair.Value;
     else
          zoomFact = pair.Value;
}


//you could use here populated variables
```